# Media not displaying other users uploads - WordPress 4.9.2

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

I am currently running on **Wordpress 4.9.2** and i recently changed the user id's of two admins from phpMyAdmin and made the changes on the tables wp_users, wp_users_meta, wp_posts and everything seems to be working fine except when i access Media -> Library the uploads made by other users are not displayed. I tried logging in to another admin's account and it seems to be the same there.

I am pretty sure that no one have added any custom function to restrict other users from viewing other's media. I have WordFence installed but i dont remember seeing an option for disabling other users medias either.

I tried disabling and enabling all the plugins in use one by one. Nothing seems to solve the issue.

Have anyone came across any similar issue and found anything that works?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why did you change the IDs? Did you change the other tables? Have you tried changing them back?

Comment: Hi Tom, Normally i used to change the ID in all my websites as soon as i am done with the installation as i dont prefer keeping the default id as 1.

I changed it using the SQL code 

'UPDATE wp_users SET id = 5789 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE wp_usersmeta SET user_id = 5789 WHERE user_id = 1;
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 5789 WHERE post_author = 1;'

I tried creating a new administrator and set that accounts id as 1 and tried if that account atleast would be able to see all the media files, but that dint work either.

Comment: You could just create a second user and delete the first, manually changing the IDs in the database is more trouble than its worth. Or just set the user with ID 1 to a contributor or subscriber role. Your best bet is to undo what you did

Comment: Did that, The issue is still there.

Comment: and you're sure this isn't a theme issue? Does it happen in the twentyseventeen theme? I'd restore to backups from before you did the SQL change, it's a very non-standard practice